# Effect of Modified Utility Function on Initial and End Values of Capital, Labor and Production

Tags: macroeconomics

I am trying to model a transition path of an economy exposed to a permanent shock to government spending on dynare via matlab.

We start with these model equations (standard dynare code format).

```
c(+1) = c* beta*(1+alpha*k^(alpha-1)-delta);
y = k(-1)^alpha;
k = (y-c)+(1-delta)*k(-1)-g;
```

Where alpha, beta are constants, `g` is exogenous (the shock), and `c`, `y`, `k` are consumption, production, and capital respectively.

We then want to change our utility function to

[$$U = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \frac{C_t^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}$$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSxDt.png)

Note that the first equation in the model is basically an Euler Equation, so only that will change if the utility model changes.

I get that the derivative of modified $U$ at time $t$ is $b^t*C_t^{-\sigma}$, which when put into the Euler Equation makes the dynare model

```
c(+1)^(-sigma) = c^(-sigma)*beta*(1+alpha*k^(alpha-1)-delta);
```

But if I do this, then the steady state values of `K` and thus `Y` and `C` do not change because the two `c`s become 1 when divided out at steady state…which I feel is somehow wrong.